# Spam link text when searching for company directors' name

Tags: search-engines

It was brought to my attention that if you search for the name of one of our directors (with the intent to find there profile page on our site) They come up as the first link in most search engines as you would expect but the link text is just pure spam.

the three search string I have tested on Google, Bing, Ask, and Yahoo have all returned similar results.

Here is a list of the search strings:

> Paolo rossi futex
>
> Mark rossi futex
>
> Marco rossi futex
>
> Dan Goldberg futex

Any idea what might be causing this I have searched through as much of the sites code as I can and cant find anything wrong with it.

Comment: Use Google Webmaster Tools to see how Google views your site. From somewhere, those spam words are being injected into your page. Do you advertise at all? Copy part of the text from the search engines, view your page then Right Click -> View Source (Or Page Source, etc), then Ctrl + F and search your page for that text.

Comment: Ok so I think I found the problem and have removed some hidden links that were in one of the word press files, but the results are still the same is there a way to force Google and others to update or will I just have to wait till the next time the bots pass?

Comment: Submitting a sitemap or "fetch page as Googlebot" will help to speed up the process. Just for curiosity, what exactly caused this?

Comment: There were some links to pharmaceutical websites in a div with display none in the footer of the WP theme we use, I am trying to work out how they got there but have come up blank. If you would like feel free to add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Usually things like this are caused by hackers exploiting WP bugs or bad filesystem permissions. Did you update to the last version of WP after cleaning that footer?

Comment: Sadly the site is totally dependant on the version of WP we are using but im hoping to fix that soon. Also its on a shared host so I put a ticket in for them to check there settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alex figured out, the issues were caused by a hidden link in the WP theme footer.

In order to have the changes reflected in Google (Or other search engines), request to have the site recrawlled and it should be changed in a few days to a week.